# Translate disabled attribute of form to form elements inside ng-container

Tags: angular, angular9

How to translate disabled attribute of form to form elements inside ng-container?

```
<form [disabled]="readonly">
 <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tOptions; context: { model: context, name 'id'}"></ng-container>
</form>

<ng-template #tOptions let-model="model" let-name="name">
 <select [name]="name" [(ngModel)]="model">
  <option [ngValue]="0">Zero</option>
  <option [ngValue]="1">One</option>
 </select>
</ng-template>
```

When **readonly** is true the select is still enabled. If the select is simply inside the form without ng-container then it will be disabled.

Comment: I'm getting `Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'form'`

Comment: pass also "readonly"  in context: `context:{model:context,name:'id',readonly:readonly}`

Comment: Ye, it looks like the possible solution. But I've hoped that some built-in feature exists.